# how to get bootstap popover to work?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I trying to create a bootstrap popover for decimals and displaying that decimal in the popover, this is the template:

```
<span
     ng-bind-html="amount1">
</span>
```

At the moment I have defined my popover like this:

```
<h1 popover-template="myPopoverTemplate.html" popover-trigger="mouseenter" ng-bind-html="amount1"></h1>
<h1 popover-template="'myPopoverTemplate.html'" popover-trigger="mouseenter" ng-bind-html="amount2"></h1>
```

Is it possible to use the same popover template for the 2 amounts?

plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/hJI6u4yo2DLqUhsyWFe5?p=preview

Comment: See new edited answer and plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with your ng-bind-html="amount1" use ng-sanitize for it  where it is giving an error

"Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context."

[image]

I understood your problem you want to show amount1 on popover of amount1 and amount2 on popover2 using same template,Here is your solution

HTML code:

```
 <body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

  <div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

&nbsp; &nbsp;
   <span popover-template="'myPopoverTemplate.html'" popover-trigger="mouseenter" ng-bind-html="amount1" ng-mouseenter="flag=true"> </span>
    <span popover-template="'myPopoverTemplate.html'" popover-trigger="mouseenter" ng-bind-html="amount2" ng-mouseenter="flag=false"> </span>

  </div>
</body>
```

Angular Code:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize']).controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.amount1 ='10000';
  $scope.amount2 ='20000';
});
```

Template Code:

```
<span ng-if='flag' ng-bind-html="amount1">

</span>
<span ng-if='flag === false' ng-bind-html='amount2'>
  </span>
```

plunker for the solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/wxZ3H1yjkMKvUldq8Ccv?p=preview
(New Plunker)

Comment: I still would like to use ng-bind-html

Comment: this issue with sanitize is fixed

Comment: see the new answer ,there was ng-sanitize dependency was missing and its file for missing watch new edited plunker

Comment: Look in the question there are 2 amounts and I wanna know if it's possible to use the same popovertemplate by somehow passing in the amount.

Comment: which means you want use amount 1 and amount2 both in a same template??

Answer (score 1):

Please refer: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

you will get the example how to show popover.

Comment: I would like to use the same template, ie show amount1 in the popover when hovering over amount1 and show amount2 when hovering over amount2.